# Do dessicants work inside of a freezer?

Tags: water, decomposition, process-chemistry

I learned that water sublimates when frozen, which prompts me to ask:

Do dessicants work inside a freezer?

While dessication inside of a freezer is unlikely to remove large quantities of water fast, it intuitively seems to me that maybe it could enhance the depth of dessication (i.e. how little traces of water ultimately are left) by certain dessicants (maybe by improving the water-dessicant affinity and/or stabilize higher hydration states of the dessicant used).

Would it be a good strategy do the bulk of dessication inside a dessicator, and throw in a product in the freezer alongside a well selected dessicant expecting it to slowly dessicate to very low trace of water over time this way?

Are some dessicants better suited for this (e.g. that dessicate by trapping away water by adsorbtion?) than others (e.g. that dessicate by trapping away water by forming higher hydration states?)?

Comment: Water does not sublime when frozen, you need a very low pressure as well.

Comment: First google (highlighted) result says: "For those of us interested in the water cycle, sublimation is most often used to describe the process of snow and ice changing into water vapor in the air without first melting into water."

Comment: You are reading out of context and this is why random searches are dangerous. Frozen water does not sublime under ordinary pressures. You need very low pressure for ice sublimation to occur. Your freezer will not have sunlight. When we talk of sublimation in very cold climates, sunlight is required for this process. This is a separate mechanism. I do not know the mechanism of that. You need about "0.00604 atm" to cause sublimation of frozen water in a laboratory!

Comment: I don't understand this well. But surely if it occurs at atmospheric pressure with sunlight it occurs to some degree in a freezer? As you state, wikipedia reads: "The loss of snow from a snowfield during a cold spell is often caused by sunshine acting directly on the upper layers of the snow. Ablation is a process that includes sublimation and erosive wear of glacier ice."

Comment: @AChem, water most definitely does sublime at low temperatures! For example, look at an ice-cube tray kept for a few months in a freezer at -30°C, and notice how little is left. See this table, https://biopharma.co.uk/blog/2015/03/30/vapour-pressure-of-ice/, for example that show ices still has a comparatively high vapor pressure well below freezing

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, Indeed, tt is a game of vapor pressure of ice-water equilibrium in the ambient. If it drops below 0.006 atm, it will start to sublime. However, the timescale, the OP is interested in, pressure has to be dropped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an effective  desiccant would help lower the amount of water vapor in a container and speed freeze drying **in a sealed system**. That said, [freeze-drying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-drying) usually employs continuous vacuum, because it is more effective than most desiccants at low temperature. There are [many choices](https://www.agmcontainer.com/blog/desiccant/selecting-desiccant/), such as silica gel and clays, and reactive chemicals such as [calcium hydroxide $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$](https://www.sorbentsystems.com/desiccants_charts.html), that might be useful.

Water is a bit unusual in having a comparatively high vapor pressure at temperatures well below its freezing point. For example, in a home freezer at -30°C (~243 K), ice cubes will sublime from an open tray in a few months *without* help from a desiccant or vacuum pump. At that temperature, the [pressure would still be ~0.4 mbar](https://biopharma.co.uk/blog/2015/03/30/vapour-pressure-of-ice/). However, if you could evacuate that freezer, they'd disappear more quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know which dessicants are more prescribed for this than others? And which ones are proscribed, if any? Am I for instance more likely to get very low residual water in the product with Na2SO4 or with Silica Gel? Thank you!

Comment: From the links cited, you *might* try a large amount of finely divided silica gel or CaO, carefully dried and *kept* dry, away from moist air, before sealing in a moisture-proof container (even polyethylene allows moisture through, albeit slowly). Note that CaO forms Ca(OH)2 in air, which can attack glassware.